# How to stop multiprocessing.Pool.map on exception

Tags: python

When I raise an exception inside my `thread_function`, it doesn't stop the rest of the `map` processing. I'd like to stop it.

```
def thread_function(n):
    if n == 10:
        raise Exception('Stop everything!')

pool = Pool(processes = 4)
pool.map(thread_function, range(1, 1000), chunksize = 1)
```

I'd expect no more processing after one thread reached `n == 10`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this directly with `map` but you can monitor an `async_map` like this...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def thread_function(n):
    if n == 10:
        print('Raising Exception')
        raise Exception('Stop everything!')
    print(n)
    time.sleep(0.1)

pool = Pool(processes = 4)
result = pool.map_async(thread_function, range(1, 1000), chunksize = 1)
while not result.ready():
    if not result._success:
        print('Exiting for failure')
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
        break
```

Comment: This will consume one core just to run the main thread in the while loop right?

Comment: If you put a time.sleep(0.01) in the monitor loop it will consume virtually no CPU time, though the response to stopping will lag just a bit.